# What is analog for CTCallStateIncoming in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios10, core-telephony, callkit

Before iOS 10 we can use `[[self.call callState] isEqualToString:@"CTCallStateIncoming"]` to detect incoming calls. In IOS10 callState deprecated and *Replaced by CallKit/CXCall.h properties*. But there is no such status like "Incoming" in CallKit, they came up with "outgoing", "onHold", "hasConnected",  "hasEnded" statuses. **I need Incoming or analog**. Any workarounds so far? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You can make final else result as "Incoming". Because you can observe all other call states except incoming.

Comment: I can try, but don't think this is going to be consistent. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: This solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use CallKit's `CXCallObserver` and `CXCall` APIs and use the following condition to detect when a given `CXCall` is incoming (`!isOutgoing`), has not yet been answered (`!hasConnected`), and has not ended (`!hasEnded`):

```
!cxCall.isOutgoing && !cxCall.hasConnected && !cxCall.hasEnded
```

Comment: Thank you, it may work, but how about call.onHold status? So full expression should say ((!call.isOutgoing) && (!call.hasConnected) && (!call.hasEnded) && (!call.onHold)). And you see how unstable it is? My point is we need direct expression, not combination of negative ones.